# How to test 'next/router' with React testing library and vitest

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm using Next.js 14 with `/pages' and in one of the pages I have this hook, where fetches data to know of we have to redirect the user to an interal page or to another website. We have to do this. The question is how can I test this hook.

I'm using React testing library (with vitest) and I have try several things but I'm having problems with the router.

useRedirect.ts

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from '@/services/fetchData';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export function useRedirect(data) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const canRedirect = await fetchData(data);
      setCanCheckIn(canRedirect);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!redirect) { window.location.href = 'https://www.externalUrl.com'; }
    if (redirect) {
      router.push({
        pathname: '/pages/another',
        query: {
          lastname: 'doe',
        },
      });
    }
  }, [redirect]);
}
```

Example test:

```js
import { waitFor, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { fetchData } from '@/services/fetchData';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

// Mock the external modules
vi.mock('@/services/fetchData', () => ({
  fetchData: jest.fn(),
}));

vi.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('useRedirect Hook', () => {
  it('can redirect', async () => {

  const mockPush = jest.fn();
  useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
    push: mockPush,
  }));

  fetchData.mockResolvedValue({ redirect: true });

  const dummyData = { /* my object */ };

  renderHook(() => useRedirect(dummyData));

  await waitFor(() => expect(mockPush).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });

  it('redirects to an external URL', async () => {
    fetchData.mockResolvedValue({ redirect: false });

     const dummyData = { /* my object */ };

    renderHook(() => useRedirect(dummyData));

    await waitFor(() => expect(window.location.href).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.externalUrl.com'));
   });
});
```

But the don't work correctly.

What would be the best way to test this hook?